# "exception class/object expected" hash object cannot be rescued in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, exception

```
begin
  hash = {"a" => "b"}
  raise hash
rescue Exception => e
  p e.message
end
```

Why i am not getting raised hash object in result, instead i am getting error - "exception class/object expected"

Answer (score 12):

Here's you're getting an error about the way that you're raising an error.

When you say `raise` you need to pass it an "exception class/object".

Some examples using built-in errors

```
raise(StandardError, "my message")

raise ArgumentError, "message"

raise NoMethodError
```

And creating a custom error class:

```
class MyError < StandardError
end

raise MyError, "message"
```

Comment: You can't raise hash to string. You have to raise an actual error object like `StandardError`.

Comment: require 'json'
begin
  hash = {"a" => "b"}
  raise StandardError,hash
rescue Exception => e
  q =  e.message
  p q
  p q.to_json
end
it should print "{\"a\":\"b\"}" but it prints "\"{\\\"a\\\"=>\\\"b\\\"}\"". Any reason?

Comment: i don't know, maybe post a new question about it.

Comment: If you type `puts q.class` and `puts q` you'll see that `q` is a String containing a fragment of Ruby: the hash you put into the exception has been turned into a string representation. The `p` command prints things you give it in a way that you can copy-paste them into Ruby code and get that particular object, so it adds the " characters on either side and uses `\"` to escape the " characters that form part of the string representation of the hash (and \\ for \ ). If you want the hash back from the string, try 'puts (eval q).class' and 'puts (eval q)["a"]' you'll find it gives 'Hash` and `b`.